# How to add files to github from directory without this direcotry?

Tags: github, project-management

I have a local project folder with the structure (for exapmle) like that:

```
/project_folder
|
|->/some_class
|  |-> class1.cpp
|  |-> class1.h
|  |-> class2.h
|
|->/out
|  |-> program.exe
|
|->readme.txt
|->info.xml
```

How add only files form that folder to repo without that folder? I would like to achieve a result like that in GitHub repo:

```
/github_repo
|
|-> class1.cpp
|-> class1.h
|-> class2.h
|-> program.exe
|->readme.txt
|->info.xml
```

Comment: It may be helpful to understand why you want that structure. Part of the idea is for other users to easily build and extend you project. This seems like a delivery mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is:

- keep the structure as-is: the readme and info.xml will provide useful information to anyone (including you) cloning the repository later
- make sure the out folder is ignored (add a `.gitignore` file with `/out/` in it)

Then add, commit and push the project content to a GitHub repository.